# [PhoneGap][Check Connection] Not work from the sample in http://docs.phonegap.com

Tags: cordova

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.3.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">


function load()
{
    checkConnection();
}

function checkConnection() 
{
    alert('0000');
    var networkState = navigator.network.connection.type;

    alert('111');

    var states = {};
    states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
    states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
    states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
    states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';
    alert('2222');
    alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);

    //if (networkState != Connection.NONE){
    // redirecting to index page

}

</script>

</head>
<body onload="load()">
</body>
</html>
```

Hi all, I know there are many samples that used to check internet connection, I hope this will be not treated as repeated post.

I wondering why cannot process to alert 111

Is there any problems with `"var networkState = navigator.network.connection.type;"`

But, mostly I reference the coding from http://docs.phonegap.com

Could anyone tell me where is going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are using old code on a new version of PhoneGap. PhoneGap changed connection API to use **navigator.connection.type** from version 2.2.0 onwards.

Comment: I wonder does it work if I open the page in either computer's browser nor phone's browser? because i found that it seems not work after changing to navigator.connection.type and just check it in my computer's browser. and it does not alert 111

Comment: It wont work in computer's browser nor in mobile browser. it will work only while running as phonegap app.

Comment: further edited: I tested it in my mobile app, and can just alert up to 111 and then there is a blank page

Comment: i have already checked the value in app/res/xml/config.xml and app/AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: btw is it possible to also help me hv a look on my another question =p http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15366362/intermittent-success-with-phonegap-logins

Comment: Since you are here, please mark the answer which helped you the most so that it can be helpful for others.